# Group_concat use?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have three tables in my DB, Student, Participant, and Activity. I'm trying to pull ALL the student names, activity names, and activity costs for all students participating in a certain activity. I'm wondering if this is possible. Here is the DB if you want to take a look: http://pastebin.com/QCsQfEKF

Basically I want a table that looks like this:
(ex. data)

```
Name  /         Activities        /Activities Cost
carl  /basketball, golf           /$500
jane  /pottery, skydiving, golf   /$600
```

and I want the data selected by giving a certain activty that they all participate in.

I know how to do all of it except for the, selecting those who are all in a certain activity, part.

Comment: Activities Cost is the sum of the costs of all the activities?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes.

Comment: Here's your schema in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e0b2/1 hit (build schema and you can start querying your data)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d283b/4 – not quite as sophisticated as Michael’s solution, since it just uses FIND_IN_SET to select only records that include the activity you’re locking for … but it gets the job done.

Comment: @CBroe, do you think there is a benefit to using michaels solution rather than yours? the results are the same.

Comment: My solution is rather “quick&dirty”. For one, it uses a string function (`FIND_IN_SET`) to check whether the activity you’re looking for is in the concatenated activities, and it uses `HAVING` to select only those records that match – `HAVING` is applied at the very last, so normally you’d try to avoid it for “cost” reasons; but since it is only applied on the GROUPed records here anyway, I don’t think that matters this much. If you really want to know which solution fares better, use `EXPLAIN` to see what is really going on in the database, how many records are processed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need several joins. Most importantly, to get the activity that they all participate in, you may use a separate joined alias (join more than once against `participants` and `activities`).  One of the aliased joins is limited in the `WHERE` clause to only those having the desired activity, to return a list of student ids.  Then you use that list to form the rest of your query.

```
SELECT
  s.stu_fname,
  s.stu_lname,
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.act_name) AS Activities,
  SUM(a.act_fee) AS `Activities Cost`
FROM
  /* These first two joins doing go into the SELECT list.
     They are used to get the list of students with your desired activity
     and will be used in the WHERE clause */
  participant plimit
  INNER JOIN activity alimit ON plimit.act_id = alimit.act_id
  /* Only include those students from the first 2 joins */
  INNER JOIN student s ON plimit.stu_id = s.stu_id
  /* Then join through the participants to get all activities for those students */
  INNER JOIN participant p ON s.stu_id = p.stu_id
  /* And to get the names of the activities */
  INNER JOIN activity a ON p.act_id = a.act_id
/* Limit to only those students with golf */
WHERE alimit.act_name = 'pottery'
/* Apply the aggregate GROUP BY to the rest of the columns in the SELECT */
GROUP BY 
  s.stu_id,
  s.stu_fname,
  s.stu_lname
```

Here it is in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37860/6

Comment: This worked brilliantly but I also want to fully understand what is happening so I ask, would you mind explaining what the 's' after student the 'p' after participant and the 'a' after activity do?

Comment: @carlgoodtoseeyou Those are aliases for the tables. They serve 2 purposes 1) less typing 2) You can't use the same table twice unless you give one of them a different alias to make them distinguishable. So we used `activity` twice, once as `a` and the other as `alimit`, same for `participant`.

Comment: Optionally, the `AS` keyword might make it clearer:  `FROM participant AS plimit INNER JOIN activity AS alimit....`

Comment: ahhh, so the AS is just optional then?

Comment: Yes it's optional https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html _A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or tbl_name alias_name_